# Transform List to List<List> according the source List content

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have following object `DataPoint`:

```
public class DataPoint {
   private String name:
   private int uploadIndex;
   ...
}
```

I have List:

```
{uploadIndex:1, name:"name_1"}
{uploadIndex:5, name:"name_2"}
{uploadIndex:3, name:"name_3"}
{uploadIndex:3, name:"name_4"}
{uploadIndex:4, name:"name_5"}
{uploadIndex:5, name:"name_6"}
{uploadIndex:2, name:"name_7"}
{uploadIndex:4, name:"name_8"}
```

I want to transform it to the `List<List<DataPoint>>` sorted by `uploadIndex`.
Result should be(ordering inside the internal list is not important):

```
{
   {uploadIndex:1, name:"name_1"}
} 
{
   {uploadIndex:2, name:"name_7"}
} 
{
   {uploadIndex:3, name:"name_3"}
   {uploadIndex:3, name:"name_4"}
} 
{
   {uploadIndex:4, name:"name_5"}
   {uploadIndex:4, name:"name_8"}
} 
{    
   {uploadIndex:5, name:"name_2"}
   {uploadIndex:5, name:"name_6"}
}
```

I wrote following code:

```
List<DataPoint> dataPoints = getFromDb();
Map<Integer, List<DataPoint>> groupedDataPoints = dataPoints.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DataPoint::getUploadIndex, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
List<List<DataPoint>> groupedList = new ArrayList<>(groupedDataPoints.values());
```

**1. Does this code guarantee the ordering?

2. Is there more concise way to implement it?**

Comment: Yes, but I guess there is no guarantee on what order objects having same `uploadIndex` would be ordered

Comment: @user7 ordering inside the internal list is not important for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 dataPoints.stream()
           .collect(
                 Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                      Collectors.groupingBy(
                         DataPoint::getUploadIndex, 
                         TreeMap::new, 
                         Collectors.toList()
                      )
                 ),
                      map -> new ArrayList(map.values())
           );
```

You could use `Collectors.collectingAndThen`; other than that your solution looks fine to me.

Comment: For objects with same `uploadIndex`, this will collect in the order in the input right? In other words, there is no sorting on `name`